# Put real time (non static) on qt (c++)

Tags: c++, qt

i want put the real time on qt, but non static

I have this code:

```
QDateTime dateTime = dateTime.currentDateTime();
QString dateTimeString = dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss");
ui->data->setText(dateTimeString);
```

but it shows only a static dateTime and i want the real dateTime (change every second)

Comment: Where do you call your code? Do you call it every frame / every second, or is it just called once?

Comment: Just once... On the start of Window

Comment: Use a QTimer to call it every second or so.

Comment: In the same thread?

Comment: Likely In the same widget

Comment: You've demonstrated that you know how to show the current time in your widget. So the underlying question is how to have something (updating the widget, in this case) happen every second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done!

Header:

```
    private:
    int timerId;

    protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event);
```

Source:

```
timerId = startTimer(1000);
....

void paginavenda::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
  QDateTime dateTime = dateTime.currentDateTime();
  QString dateTimeString = dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
  ui->data->setText(dateTimeString);
}
```